# RequireJS How to run correctly videojs-vtt-thumbnails?

Tags: requirejs, video.js

I am using the **RequireJS** to load the **videojs** and use the **videojs-vtt-thumbnails** plugin.
I did everything like here in this guide https://github.com/chrisboustead/videojs-vtt-thumbnails
My config file looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "",
    "paths": {
        "app": "",
        "video.js": "https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.5/video.min",
        "videojs-vtt-thumbnails.min": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-vtt-thumbnails@0.0.13/dist/videojs-vtt-thumbnails.cjs.min"
    }
});
```

This is what the **videojs-vtt-thumbnails** calling code looks like.

```
    require(['video.js', 'videojs-vtt-thumbnails.min'], function(videojs) {
    var showcasePlayer = videojs('my-player', opions, function () {
        showcasePlayer.vttThumbnails({
        src: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sprite.mysite.com/123456-spr-w120.vtt'
        });
    });
   });
```

Next, I call the **videojs-vtt-thumbnails** plugin

Finally, I get this error:
"TypeError: showcasePlayer.vttThumbnails is not a function"

Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/SergeyKozlov/k8azq9f5/

How to run correctly **videojs-vtt-thumbnails** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is the lack of a description of the dependencies in to **shim** of **requirejs.config**:

```
shim: {
    'video.min': {
        deps: ['videojs-vtt-thumbnails.min']
    }
}
```

In my case, the problem is solved.